# can't install software-center on kali linux 2.0

Tags: kali-linux

I've just installed Kali linux 2.0 and when I tried to install software center by typing `apt-get install software-center` it didn't work so I did some googleing. And the only answer I found is to update and upgrade by `apt-get update` `apt-get upgrade` `apt-get dist-upgrade` it shows me this:

[image: Unmet dependencies]

any help

Answer (score 0):

First switch to your root account, you can also use terminal for that
use `su - root`

1. write `nano /etc/apt/sources.list` in your terminal.
2. Add these two lines in that editor.

   ```
   deb http://http.kali.org/ /kali main contrib non-free
   deb http://http.kali.org/ /wheezy main contrib non-free
   ```
3. Save and exit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>), Y.
4. Write `apt-get update`
5. Write `apt-get install synaptic`
6. Write `apt-get install software-center`